# Issue with Constraintlayout when defining the listview items with the divider spacing

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a dumb problem about the dividers with the listview when using ConstraintLayout (that I don't have using a RelativeLayout).

Below is the image describing my problem. The space with the upper divider is not the same with the lower one:

[image]

And here is my xml file.
What do I need to do so the text is right in the middle?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appd_permlist"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_xlarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appd_risk"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appd_risk"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@color/lgrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appd_permlist"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appd_permlist" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions:

- The height of the row should be defined by the `appd_risk` view (since it has a fixed height)
- The `appd_permlist` should be vertically centered in the space defined as above

In that case, here's a layout that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appd_permlist"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_xlarge"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/appd_risk"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appd_risk"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:background="@color/lgrey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've changed the ConstraintLayout's height to `wrap_content`, and then I've changed the `appd_risk` top/bottom constraints to `parent`, which makes the row be 30dp tall (or whatever size you pick for `appd_risk`).

Then I've removed the top margin from `appd_permlist` and additionally added a bottom constraint to the `parent`. This will vertically center `appd_permlist`.

Comment: Works great. I will review your changes later and will probably get back to you with a question or 2. Many thanks!

Comment: If I want to make the space inside the divider higher, without touching the height of appd_risk, would you do it this way: set the ConstraintLayout's height to a fixed size (for ex 200dp), and change the top/bottom appd_permlist constraint to 16 dp (for ex)?